# Excel function to split string and transpose

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement where I need to split a string '/' separated and transpose into rows and get data from another column. I need an Excel function. I am using Office 2016/ 365.

If I add a new project or  new name it will reflect in output.

```
Col A  Names
------ -------
Proj1   Nam1/Nam2/Nam3
Proj2   Nam3/Nam5
Proj3   Nam2/Nam4
Proj4   Nam1/Nam5/Nam7

Expected Output
Nam1   Proj1
Nam1   Proj4
Nam2   Proj1
Nam2   Proj3  .. and so on
If above is not possible then maybe I can have something like below and then use PIVOT table.

colA   ColB  ColC   ColD  ColE ......
Nam1   Proj1 Proj4
Nam2   Proj1 Proj3
```

Comment: Using power pivot or vba would be the easiest.  There are many questions here that show you how to do that.

Comment: Also in your verbiage it states Excel 2016 and Office 365, but you tagged it Excel 2010, why?

Comment: @scott-craner i moved excel 2010 I was just hoping if anyone from there may know the solution. I have to use function cannot use VBA macros. Thanks for replying

Comment: It is going to be very difficult in 2016, requiring many helper ranges.

Comment: @scott-craner can we get the text split into columns then i will use pivot table

Comment: There are many many posts out here on how to split a string into various columns using formula.

Comment: thanks  got it :-) =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($G5,"/",REPT(" ",LEN($G5))),COLUMNS($G:G)*LEN($G5)-(LEN($G5)-1),LEN($G5)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you stated that Office 365 is an option:

```
=LET(
    p,A1:A4,
    m,MAX(BYROW(B1:B4,LAMBDA(z,LEN(z)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(z,"/",""))+1))),
    n,TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(p),m,LAMBDA(a,b,IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(B1:B4,a),"/"),b),"")))),
    o,HSTACK(n,INDEX(p,SEQUENCE(m*ROWS(p),,1,1/m))),
    SORT(FILTER(o,n<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW Scott you are genius, I m trying hard to make  your formula work, but I am not able to make it work, i changed the columns too . I am sure it will work..but I am still trying  will let you know

Comment: @RajivA It uses many functions that may or may not be available in your version of Office 365.  Namely `TOCOL`,`MAKEARRAY`,`TEXTSPLIT`, and `HSTACK`  They are on the cusp of being released to everyone, but they are rolling them out in parts.

Comment: Yes you are right, TOCOL is not available in my version :-( but I am super impressed the way you created the expression! You are very savvy with excel. I will to check with my desktop team if they can do an update of office 365.

Comment: I forgot to mention  Many many thanks for your time and effort It is great to learn about how these new functions.Can I achieve the 2nd expected option  where I will have the projects in columns per person without the new functions

Comment: it would be very hard to do so.  I do not have the time to work it out.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your valuable time.Thank you very much again for all this help